# ERROR: Problems trying to get index of users! using moodle authentication module of drupal services

Tags: php, drupal-7, moodle

Currently I am working in Drupal 7 & Moodle2.3 Integration, but I got error "ERROR: Problems trying to get index of users! "

https://github.com/cannod/moodle-drupalservices/blob/a2c607368d7f2087e575c006425eb2da39bf02cb/README.md

== EDIT (Comment added by author) ==

I get chance to review the file, so it calls auth.php.

```
$drupal_users = $apiObj->Index('muser');
if (is_null($drupal_users) || empty($drupal_users)) { 
    die("ERROR: Problems trying to get index of users!\n");
```

And, function call Index in REST-API.php file...

```
$callerId = 'RemoteAPI->Index'; 
if (!$this->VerifyLoggedIn( $callerId )) { 
    return NULL; // error 
} 
$url = $this->gateway.$this->endpoint.'/'.$resourceType . $options;
```

Answer (score 0):

i am in a similar situation too. I am trying to use the drupal services but until now i am not able to setup it successfully. I was about to ask a question here too, but i noticed that recently the developer updated his wiki page on Github. So, you can watch there how it goes and maybe you can find a solution to your issue.
Hope it helps..

Comment: finally successfully done integration Drupal7 & Moodle2.3, Let me know if you need any help from my side.